# Efficient "destiny knot" partial inheritance function

Tags: python, optimization, random

In the Pokémon games (since Gen VI), [Destiny Knot](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Destiny_Knot) is an item that, while held, will cause a parent to pass on some of its stats to any children it may have.

I'm looking to create a function in python 3 that will create a copy of a list of numbers that is partially randomly generated, and partially inherited from a "parent". Here is my first implementation:

```
def destiny_knot(parent, prob):
    child = []
    for n in parent :
        if np.random.rand(1)<prob :
            child.append(n)
        else :
            child.append(np.random.normal())
    return child
```

Which works as intended when ran:

```
foo = range(10)
destiny_knot(foo, 0.5)

[3.7189086135642975, 1, 0.6303126955135048, -0.9230447017112412, 4, 5, 6, 0.8633075878923896, 0.4633879779484653, -1.5192557497361636]
```

However, it's quite obvious to me that this will take a long time when actually implemented for the uses I'm looking for: each of my lists will be thousands, if not hundreds of thousands, of elements, and I'll be aiming to generate thousands of these.

I was thinking about determining a number of elements that will be inherited, and generating N minus that many random numbers, but I would also need them to be inherited at the correct positions, which adds a layer of complexity to the whole problem.

What would be the most efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're using NumPy:

```
def destiny_knot(parent: np.ndarray, prob: float):
    child = parent.copy() # Inherit everything
    # Mask for future random numbers
    am_I_random = np.random.rand(parent.size) > prob
    # Generate random numbers and put them into `child`
    # according to the mask `am_I_random`
    child[am_I_random] = np.random.normal(size=am_I_random.sum())

    return child
```

Make sure that `parent` is an array of floats - otherwise the floats returned by `np.random.normal(size=am_I_random.sum())` will be converted to integers or whatever the type of `parent`.

---

Example run:

```
>>> parent = np.asfarray([1,2,3,6,4,2,5])
>>> destiny_knot(parent, .7)
array([ 1.        ,  2.        ,  3.        ,  6.        , -1.10456035,
        2.        ,  2.43449116])
>>> destiny_knot(parent, .5)
array([-0.67617249,  2.        ,  3.        , -2.11637063,  0.19032201,
        2.        ,  5.        ])
```

Comment: Thank you! This is sort of what I imagined would work well, but I didn't know how to implement. I'll leave the post open in case anyone has anything even more efficient, otherwise I'll accept sometime tomorrow

Comment: using `child = np.array(parent, dtype=float)` might be safer than blindly copying, but it's not going to make much difference.  also `rand(*parent.shape)` might be slightly nicer